# SOAP and HTTP Services within the same ASP.Net Project

Tags: asp.net, web-services, cross-domain-proxy

I have an existing web service project that is using SOAP messages to communicated back and forth. I have just created what should be an HTTP service called "AJAXWebServices" that has an attribute over the service class of "[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService()]". I want this service to utilize HTTP POST/GET and the other services in the project to continue utilizing their SOAP. The AJAXWebService works fine if the ".asmx" file is in the local project but when I publish it and then make a web reference to it, and I set the service path of my ajaxToolKit:AutoCompleteExtender to "HTTP://server/folder/AJAXWebService.asmx" the page loads and when I start typing it will make the request but return an entire page of HTML instead of just the autocomplete words. It freezes my I.E. while its parsing all the XML. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Every time a user type a character your application makes a SOAP call to your webservice? I would not recommend you doing an auto-complete like that.

Comment: The SOAP are not for the autocomplete. The autocomplete is supposed to be using HTTP, it has to be atleast 3 characters and cacheing is enabled so it shouldn't need to ping the webservice again unless the user tries typing something totally different than before. How would you implement an autocomplete?

Comment: Ok. I guess I would avoid doing calls to external systems like web services to implement an autocomplete but that is just my opinion, I would definitely have the information needed for the autocomplete in the Application Cache so that is faster to read